# IP Multicast between Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, linux-networking, multicast

Our team is developing linux/windows applications for our network that are talking to each other via multicast. We had it working when we only had linux boxes on the network, but we recently added a few windows machines into the loop, and are unable to communicate between the OS's. All 3 windows machines are able to talk to one another, and all linux machines (mix of CentOS, RHEL, and Ubuntu) are able to talk to eachother. All communication is over 227.0.0.1, port 11052, and all computers on the same networksubnet. But linux cannot hear windows, and visa versa.

We have tested our software with a few different multicast testers, the most prevalent one being [mctester](https://github.com/shuque/mctester). We've verified that both the windows and linux applications work, but we are having the same issue. We even have a few windows machines running linux vm's, and even they are not even able to talk to one another over multicast.

We have other applications on both the windows and linux boxes that are successfully able to talk to one another over UDP (unicast). Is there anything special that we need to do for multicast that we did not have to do for UDP? We had to enable multicast routing on linux, but are there any settings for windows?

Comment: FYI, you should not be using multicast groups in the reserved range. You should use multicast groups in the Organization-Local Scope range of `239.0.0.0/8`.

Comment: Wireshark/tcpdump on the linux machines should show you what is up. Check all firewalls as well.